# Users who completed both events BigQuery

Tags: sql, events, google-bigquery

How to select only those users who completed both events in a session and not just one?
If you link the shortcut through "and" then the request does not work. BigQuery dataset

I tray that:

```
select
date,
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
hits.eventInfo.eventLabel,
sessionid as session,
clientid as clientid,
hits.hitId as hits
FROM `table_name`, unnest(hits) as hits 
 where _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20230220' AND '20230220'
and hits.eventInfo.eventCategory ='categoty'
and hits.eventInfo.eventAction ='click'
and hits.eventInfo.eventLabel ='lable1' and hits.eventInfo.eventLabel ='lable2`
```

in result "There is no data to display".

Comment: What's the expected result - do you want both rows or just one with a combined result?

Comment: Sessions and users who had both versions of the label in the session, and not one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) and IN operator on eventlabel to get the result you want.

See the following code as example:

```
WITH record_w_desired_label AS (select
date,
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
hits.eventInfo.eventLabel,
sessionid as session,
clientid as clientid,
hits.hitId as hits,
COUNT(DISTINCT hits.eventInfo.eventLabel) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY clientid, sessionid) AS num_desired_event_label
FROM `table_name`, unnest(hits) as hits 
where _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20230220' AND '20230220'
and hits.eventInfo.eventCategory ='categoty'
and hits.eventInfo.eventAction ='click'
and (hits.eventInfo.eventLabel in ('lable1','lable2')
)
SELECT
    date,
    eventCategory,
    eventAction,
    eventLabel,
    session,
    clientid,
    hits
FROM
    record_w_desired_label
WHERE
    num_desired_event_label = 2
```